# Retrieving Firebase Data by priority (lowest to highest) not working?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble setting the priority of my Firebase objects. Below is my attempt:

The first is how I save the `Post` object to Firebase, keeping the priority low. I would do `0 - date.getTime()` because I know that Firebase's documentation says that priority is `sorted numerically by priority, small to large.` This is what I did then:

```
private Firebase firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://<DataBase>.com/");
private Firebase currentUserPath = firebaseRef.child("users/" + userId);

public void savePostToFirebase(final Post post, Location location) {
    //Firstly, we need to keep track of all posts so we put them into a posts path.
    final Firebase postsRef = firebaseRef.child("posts").push();
    String postId = postsRef.getKey();
    post.setId(postId);
    Date date = new Date();
    postsRef.setValue(post, 0 - date.getTime());

    //Next, we need to set that post in your own post's path to be true
    currentUserPath.child("/posts/" + postsRef.getKey()).setValue(true);
}

public void getPosts(final Boolean loggedIn, final Activity activity) {
    final Firebase postsRef = firebaseRef.child("/posts");
    Firebase linkRef = currentUserPath.child("/posts");
    linkRef.orderByPriority().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            postsRef.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).orderByPriority().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        System.out.println("Post Priority " + dataSnapshot.getPriority());
                    Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    application.getPostsAdapter().getPosts().add(post);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong. I set the priority from `smallest to largest` and also made sure that when retrieving the `Post` I was using the `orderByPriority()` API to do so. I print out the priority of my `Post` object but it ends up being `null` always. If anyone could point me in the right direction that'd be great. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is a sample of what my data looks like. the .prioirty isn't showing up in my data... I'm not sure why. though...

```
  "posts" : {
    "-KN_oJAgTNJHwJbqY3qk" : {
      "id" : "-KN_oJAgTNJHwJbqY3qk",
      "name" : "Stephen",
      "numComments" : 1,
      "posterUserId" : "10206287838487450",
      "privacy" : "Public",
      "status" : "first post",
      "timeStamp" : "07/25/2016 11:08:05 PM",
      "title" : "first post"
    },
    "-KN_oN9_Xmw5ULnBRYM7" : {
      "id" : "-KN_oN9_Xmw5ULnBRYM7",
      "name" : "Stephen",
      "numComments" : 0,
      "posterUserId" : "10206287838487450",
      "privacy" : "Public",
      "status" : "second post",
      "timeStamp" : "07/25/2016 11:08:21 PM",
      "title" : "second post"
    },
    "-KN_obYGug9Tdrzufbqc" : {
      "id" : "-KN_obYGug9Tdrzufbqc",
      "name" : "Stephen",
      "numComments" : 0,
      "posterUserId" : "10206287838487450",
      "privacy" : "Public",
      "status" : "this post",
      "timeStamp" : "07/25/2016 11:09:24 PM",
      "title" : "third party"
    }
  },
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do. In your specific case, make sure that the `.priority` is also in the JSON, since that is quite important to your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi, I replaced the photo of my database with a photo of what my database should look like. Also, I realized that the `.priorty`is not in the JSON automatically, would I have to include this manually myself? Is there any easier way I can display this?

Comment: You can get the JSON *with* the priority by calling `DataSnapshot.exportVal()`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my apologies and maybe I am not doing this correctly but I only see that `exportVal()` is in used in the JS API. Any way to do this in Android? Thanks!

Comment: No apologies needed, I had to look this one up too: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(boolean). But to be honest: I'd prefer the actual JSON, which is easiest to get from the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for letting me know and pointing me in the right location. I tried the following: `System.out.println("Snapshot with priority: " + dataSnapshot.getValue(true));` but this seemed not to give me the priority either. This is what is printed for example: `Snapshot With priority: {posterUserId=10206287838487450, title=first post, privacy=Public, status=first post, id=-KN_oJAgTNJHwJbqY3qk, numComments=1, name=Stephen, timeStamp=07/25/2016 11:08:05 PM}`. Is it possible I may not be assigning priority correctly then?

Comment: why have you setted priority by `0-` . Is there a specific reason?

Comment: Yes because I thought that the priority is handled lowest to highest therefore if I set the priority this way the most recent posts will be displayed first

Comment: **As  a tip**  :  If you want to display in decreasing order you should rather use `99999999999-date.getTime()` because Firebase doesnt work in that way on negative value.. rather for positive value..

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try like this..

```
public void savePostToFirebase(final Post post, Location location) {
   //Firstly, we need to keep track of all posts so we put them into a posts path.

   String postId = postsRef.getKey();
   post.setId(postId);
   Date date = new Date();

   firebaseRef.child("posts").setValue(post, 0 - date.getTime());

   //Next, we need to set that post in your own post's path to be true
   currentUserPath.child("/posts/" + postsRef.getKey()).setValue(true);
}
```